# pipeline groovy - access parent groovy object in child

Tags: groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I have main groovy.v1 script as below

```
def lib = load '/var/jenkins_home/pipeline/test.groovy'
job = lib.newInstance(this, "test_user", "test_pwd")
```

also have job class as below

```
class Job {
    private def steps
    private String userName
    private String password
    Job(steps, String userName, String password) {
      
        this.steps              = steps
        this.userName           = userName
        this.password           = password
    }

    def testMethod(String userName) {
        return userName
    }
}
```

I also have dynamic child groovy.v2 as below

```
job.testMethod(test_user)
```

the problem here is I cannot access job object child groovy.v2, when I ran the pipeline it is saying no such property called job

how to access object created in main goovy.v1 in child groovy.v1